# How to select a selected value when you have a list stored in ViewData["country"] in C' MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, viewdata, selectedvalue, html-select

I have list stored in `ViewData["country"]` and I want to list this but also have a selected value.
I currently have

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlCountry", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["country"], new { @style = "Width:250px" })
```

However this just lists them all and selects the first one by default.  I want it to select the country that the user has set to their account which is stored in `@Model.Country`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SelectListItem sli = ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["country"]).AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Value == Model.Country).FirstOrDefault();
if (sli != null) {
    sli.Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: That does'nt seem to work, it seems to have a problem with the Where clause.  It keeps suggesting that I should change it to FirstOrDefault instead.

Comment: Instead of the Where clause that is

Comment: I think that is just a Resharper suggestion. .Where(x => x.Value == Model.Country).FirstOrDefault() is equivalent with .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == Model.Country)

Comment: Ah ok,  well it still doesnt seem to like either of them, it just says "Ambiguous Invocation" and also "Cannot apply operator '==' to operands of type string.

Comment: x.Value is a string. I'm guessing Model.Country isn't? Maybe something like  Model.Country.Id.ToString() or Model.Country.Name, depending on your Model.

Comment: Ok thanks, that seems to have no errors now,  so now to put that into my Html.DropDownList do I just put: @Html.DropDownList("ddlCountry", sli, new { @style = "Width:250px" })

Answer (score 0):

We are doing something similar...

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("dealerIds" , new List<SelectListItem>(((List<Company.SPPC.MVC.DealerId>)ViewData["dealerIds"]).Select(i => new SelectListItem() { Value = i.Key, Text = i.Description }).ToList())
                                , new { tabloop = "", id = "ddlDealerIds" })%>
```

Perhaps try:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlCountry",((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["country"]).Select(i => new SelectListItem() { Value = i.Country}, new { @style = "Width:250px" })
```